# MySQL Error: 1305. Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm getting

> Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION acdb_extended.player does not exist

When I attempt to call a stored procedure. The odd thing about the error is that "player" isn't the name of the stored procedure.

Here's the stored procedure code, there is probably a number of things wrong with it but it's correct as far as I can tell:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `acdb_extended`.`addAllianceMember` (IN accountNumber VARCHAR(255),
    IN userName VARCHAR(255), IN serverInitial CHAR(1), IN galaxy TINYINT(2),
    IN region TINYINT(2), IN system TINYINT(2), IN astro TINYINT(2), IN level TINYINT(2))
BEGIN
    IF player (account_number) = accountNumber
    THEN REPLACE INTO player (username)
        VALUES (userName);
    ELSE INSERT INTO player (account_number, username)
        VALUES (accountNumber, userName);
    END IF;

    IF coordinates (server_initial) = serverInitial AND
        coordinates (galaxy) = galaxy AND
        coordinates (region) = region AND
        coordinates (system) = system AND
        coordinates (astro) = astro
    THEN REPLACE INTO coordinates (player_ID)
        VALUES ((SELECT player_ID FROM player WHERE username = userName));
    ELSE INSERT INTO coordinates (player_ID, server_initial, galaxy, region, system, astro)
        VALUES ((SELECT player_ID FROM player WHERE username = userName), serverInitial,
            galaxy, region, system, astro);
    END IF;

    IF jumpgate (player_ID) = (SELECT player_ID FROM player WHERE username = userName) AND
            jumpgate (coordinates_ID) = (SELECT c.coordinates_ID FROM coordinates c, player p WHERE c.player_ID = p.player_ID
            AND p.username = userName)
    THEN REPLACE INTO jumpgate (level)
            VALUES (level);
    ELSE INSERT INTO jumpgate (player_ID, coordinates_ID, level, usable)
            VALUES ((SELECT player_ID FROM player WHERE username = userName),
                (SELECT c.coordinates_ID FROM coordinates c, player p WHERE c.player_ID = p.player_ID
                AND p.username = userName), level, TRUE);
    END IF;
END
```

And here is the SQL statement I'm using to test it:

```
CALL addAllianceMember(8494618, 'Carl', 'G', 29, 08, 10, 01, 04);
```

Any hints on where this is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `IF player (account_number) = accountNumber ...`?

Comment: Oh, I'm beginning to see the problem now. What I was trying to do was check if the COLUMN account_number from the TABLE player was the same as the VARIABLE accountNumber. How would I rephrase that?

Comment: But for which record in `player`?

Comment: All of them. I want it to run a search through the account_number column and look for a match, if it finds one then I want it to do something, if it doesn't I want it to do something else.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM player WHERE account_number = accountNumber) ...`

Comment: Okay, so I can go through and change the IF statements to one's in that format, will the THEN/ELSE parts work or are they also wrong?

Comment: Instead of your `IF ... END IF` logic, you probably want to define appropriate `UNIQUE` indexes and then use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (`REPLACE` would also do the trick, but it deletes then inserts rather than just updating existing records so data in other columns would be lost).

Comment: I have unique indexes in the player table. All the columns are unique in fact, to enforce the rule that two players can't have the same user name and account number for example. But what exactly comes after the UPDATE? Looking through the documentation it's always some expression. I'm not sure how that applies here. Can you provide an example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13166/discussion-between-eggyal-and-arcadian)

Answer (score 1):

in this line

```
IF player (account_number) = accountNumber
```

it's calling player like a function, it's look like player doesn't exists as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used Player as function just after BEGIN.

BEGIN
    IF **player (account_number)** = accountNumber